# Android Google Maps gives a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app tht uses Google Maps API v2. It works fine, except for a little annoying this, when I use the `setMyLocationEnabled(true);` method, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. I can just click "Resume" and the app continues. When running without debugger, there is nothing you can see happening.

This is what LogCat is saying:

```
09-23 22:39:31.645: I/dalvikvm(2067): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
09-23 22:39:31.645: W/dalvikvm(2067): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
09-23 22:39:32.473: W/dalvikvm(2067): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4203 (CREATOR) in Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;
```

It looks like a missing class in the library, and if I jump into the library project, I indeed do not see that class.

Is there anything I can add / fix to make this exception go away?

Comment: are you seeing this error only in debug mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that logcat error before and I noticed it is due to mismatch in my API key between debug and release mode. If you are using separate key store for debug, please make sure you have included both debug and release SHA1+package.name combos in the Google Dev Console.